# "error": "select * from `alliance` where `alliance_description` = {} - SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: alliance

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

The problem =>  "error": "select * from `alliance` where `alliance_description` = {} - SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: alliance"

> ```
> $ npm run start:dev
>
> > rest-api@1.0.0 start:dev D:\OSSE\back-end
> > nodemon src/server.js
>
> [nodemon] 2.0.7
> [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
> [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
> [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
> [nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`
> migrations [ 2, [] ]
> Listening on Port 5000!
> sqlite does not support inserting default values. Set the `useNullAsDefault` flag to hide this warning. (see docs
> ```
>
> http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert).
> GET /alliance 500 149.999 ms - 110
> sqlite does not support inserting default values. Set the `useNullAsDefault` flag to hide this warning. (see docs
> http://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert).
> GET /alliance 500 6.629 ms - 110
> GET /favicon.ico 404 0.703 ms - 40

[image: postman call to localhost:5000/alliance]

Knex.js Config

> ```
> const path = require('path')
>
> require('dotenv').config()
>
> const {
>   DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost/postgres',
> } = process.env
>
> module.exports = {
>   development: {
>     client: 'postgresql',
>     connection: DATABASE_URL,
>     pool: { min: 0, max: 100 },
>     migrations: {
>       directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'db', 'migrations'),
>     },
>     seeds: {
>       directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'db', 'seeds'),
>     },
>     useNullAsDefault: true,
>   },
>
>   production: {
>     client: 'postgresql',
>     connection: DATABASE_URL,
>     pool: { min: 0, max: 100 },
>     migrations: {
>       directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'db', 'migrations'),
>     },
>     seeds: {
>       directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'db', 'seeds'),
>     },
>     useNullAsDefault: true,
>   },
>
>   test: {
>     client: 'sqlite3',
>     connection: {
>       filename: ':memory:',
>     },
>     migrations: {
>       directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'db', 'migrations'),
>     },
>     seeds: {
>       directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'db', 'seeds'),
>     },
>     useNullAsDefault: true,
>   },
> }
> ```

Knex Connection

> ```
> const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
> const config = require('../../knexfile')[env]
> const knex = require('knex')(config)
>
> module.exports = knex
> ```

Alliance.controller

> ```
> const service = require('./alliance.service')
> const wrapper = require('../errors/asyncErrorBoundary')
>
> const list = async (req, res, next) => {
>   const { alliance_description } = req.query
>   const data = await service.list(req.query)
>   if (alliance_description) {
>     const data = await service.list(alliance_description)
>     res.json({
>       data: alliance_description,
>     })
>     return
>   }
>   return res.json({ data })
> }
>
> function allianceExists(req, res, next) {
>   const allianceId = req.params.alliance_id
>   const foundAlliance = alliance.find(
>     (alliances) => alliances.id === alliance_id
>   )
>   if (foundAlliance) {
>     res.locals.dish = foundAlliance
>     return next()
>   }
>   next({
>     status: 404,
>     message: `Alliance ID ${allianceId} Doesn't Exist`,
>   })
> }
>
> function checkAllianceId(req, res, next) {
>   const allianceId = req.params.alliance_id
>   const id = req.body.data.id
>   if (allianceId !== id && id !== undefined && (id !== '') & (id !== null)) {
>     return next({
>       status: 400,
>       message: `Alliance ID does not match route id. Alliance: ${id}, Route: ${allianceId}`,
>     })
>   }
>   return next()
> }
>
> const update = async (req, res, next) => {
>   const { alliance_id } = req.params
>   const data = await service.update(alliance_id, req.body.data)
>   res.status(200).json({
>     data: data[0],
>   })
> }
>
> const create = async (req, res, next) => {
>   const newAlliance = res.locals.validAlliance
>   const newRes = await service.create(newAlliance)
>   res.status(201).json({ data: newRes[0] })
> }
>
> const show = async (req, res, next) => {
>   const data = await service.show()
>   return res.json({ data })
> }
>
> const read = async (req, res, next) => {
>   const alliances = res.locals.alliance
>   res.status(200).json({ data: alliance[0] })
> }
>
> const isValid = (req, res, next) => {
>   if (!req.body.data)
>     return next({ status: 400, message: 'No alliance selected' })
>   const { alliance_name, alliance_description } = req.body.data
>   const requiredFields = ['alliance_name', 'alliance_description']
>   for (const field of requiredFields) {
>     if (!req.body.data[field]) {
>       return next({ status: 400, message: `Invalid input for ${field}` })
>     }
>   }
>   res.locals.validAlliance = req.body.data
>   next()
> }
>
> const destroy = async (req, res) => {
>   const { alliance_id } = rq.params
>   const des = await service.destroy(alliance_id)
>   res.status(200)
> }
>
> module.exports = {
>   list: [wrapper(list)],
>   show: [wrapper(show)],
>   read: [wrapper(checkAllianceId), wrapper(allianceExists), wrapper(read)],
>   create: [wrapper(isValid), wrapper(create)],
>   update: [wrapper(isValid), wrapper(allianceExists), wrapper(update)],
>   destroy: [wrapper(destroy)],
> }
> ```

Alliance.Router

> ```
> const router = require('express').Router()
> const controller = require('./alliance.controller')
> const methodNotAllowed = require('../errors/methodNotAllowed')
>
> router.route('/').get(controller.list).all(methodNotAllowed)
>
> router
>   .route('/:allianceId')
>   .get(controller.list)
>   .post(controller.create)
>   .put(controller.update)
>   .all(methodNotAllowed)
>
> router
>   .route('/:allianceId/:userId')
>   .get(controller.list)
>   .put(controller.update)
>   .delete(controller.destroy)
>   .all(methodNotAllowed)
>
> module.exports = router
> ```

Alliance.service

> ```
> const { default: knex } = require('knex')
>
> const listAlliancesById = (knex, allianceId) =>
>   knex('alliances as a').where({ 'a.alliance_id': allianceId })
>
> const list = (alliance_description) => {
>   return knex('alliance')
>     .select('*')
>     .from('alliance')
>     .where({ alliance_description: alliance_description })
>   // .orderBy('alliance_id')
> }
>
> const show = () => {
>   return knex('alliance').select('*')
> }
>
> const read = (alliance_id) => {
>   return knex('alliance').select('*').where({ alliance_id: alliance_id })
> }
>
> const create = (alliance) => {
>   return knex('alliance').insert(alliance, '*')
> }
> const update = (alliance_id, updatedAlliance) => {
>   return knex('alliance')
>     .where({ alliance_id: alliance_id })
>     .update(updatedAlliance)
>     .returning('*')
> }
>
> const destroy = (alliance) => {
>   return knex('alliance').delete(alliance).returning('*')
> }
>
> module.exports = {
>   list,
>   show,
>   read,
>   create,
>   listAlliancesById,
>   update,
>   destroy,
> }
> ```

Database query

[image: DBeaver Select Query of the connected database]

I hope someone can help me figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
const { default: knex } = require('knex')
const knex = require(../db/connection) // <==== ANSWER

// was missing out of the .service file
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting error from sqlite dbms:

> SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: alliance"

definitely your app is connected to sqlite and not postgresql server and it can't find that table in there.

so look into your config/connection strings to find out where your knex app is reading the database connection from